# Ruby on rails stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider following model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    # nothing in the model
end

>> rails c

>> Category.all     # works fine
```

But when I do as below, it throws the error `stack level too deep`:

```
>> Category.order("updated_at DESC") # you should assume syntax is right
```

I am having this error after upgrading ruby to 1.9.3 from 1.8.7 and rails to 3.2.0 from 3.0.4.
It was working fine before I upgraded. There was no code change at all, only versions are upgraded.

However I have another project on my machine with old versions and I'm facing no error there.

**Apparently it looks like problem is because of upgraded versions but not sure, I have read many threads on stackoverflow but did not get satisfactory answer.**

Please help I have already spent considerable time on fixing this issue with no success.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide any information. How about the stack trace to begin with?

Comment: just fyi, upgrading ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 and rails from 3.0 to 3.2 are two major upgrades. For one, hash has changed

Comment: Add a full stack trace of the error to your question.

Comment: You should do these upgrades separately—e.g., upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3, then run your tests. Then to Rails 3.1, run your tests. Then finally to Rails 3.2, and run your tests. Jumping over versions and doing multiple upgrades at once makes it difficult to track down the problem.

Comment: @MichieldeMare there are no stack traces in Ruby for "stack too deep" errors, hence why they are a pain to debug. You get an error message and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the stack size with the `ulimit` command. Maybe it's just a bit on the small side.

http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/5-ruby-stack-level-too-deep-systemstackerror